# How do I enable/disable a gameobject from a different Script?

Tags: unity

I wanted a shield around my player when my player picks it up. Now shield component is a child of object of player which is disable at start. I wanna enable it from the shield prefab. This is all in unity

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
shieldGameObject.SetActive(true);
```

You can read about it here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html

Comment: It should be noted that if you want to enable/disable a specific _component_ on a GameObject, you do that with `component.enabled = {true/false}`, e.g. `shield.enabled = true;`

Comment: It MAY be noted, since it isn't his question.